# Find the mean of two values, take two

Tags: c++

This is my generalisation of `std::midpoint` incorporating advice received for [Find the mean of two values](/q/262762/75307).  As well as supporting arithmetic types and pointers, as `std::midpoint` does, it also supports iterators, complex numbers and user-defined types such as bignums, rationals and fixed-point numbers.

As well as advice from the first review, I've made a couple of other changes:

- reject `bool` as argument type
- pedantic handling of pointer difference where the result is too large for `std::ptrdiff_t`:

  > If an array is so large (greater than `PTRDIFF_MAX` elements, but less
  > than `SIZE_MAX` bytes), that the difference between two pointers may not
  > be representable as `std::ptrdiff_t`, the result of subtracting two such
  > pointers is undefined.  — [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/ptrdiff_t) (CC-BY-SA 3.0)

```
#include <array>
#include <cmath>
#include <complex>
#include <concepts>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iterator>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

namespace toby
{
namespace detail
{
    // A point on an affine line can be compared with another, and has
    // a difference type (which may be the same type).
    template<typename T>
    concept affine_point = std::regular<T> && requires(T a, T b) {
        a < b;
        a + (b - a);
    };

    // Subtraction helper, for pedantic handling of very large arrays
    template<typename T>
    auto distance(const T& a, const T& b) {
        return b - a;
    }
    template<typename T>
    requires ( sizeof (T) < SIZE_MAX / PTRDIFF_MAX )
    std::size_t distance(const T* a, const T* b) {
        if (b < a) {
            std::swap(a, b);
        }
        // If an array has more than PTRDIFF_MAX elements,
        // subtraction is undefined if the result is not
        // representable as std::ptrdiff_t.
        std::size_t gap = 1;
        while (a + gap < b - gap) {
            gap *= 2;
        }
        // (b - gap - a) promotes to size_t if necessary
        return b - gap - a + gap;
    }

    void midpoint(bool, bool) = delete;

    template<affine_point T>
    constexpr T midpoint(const T& a, const T& b)
    {
        if (a == b) {
            // This ensures infinities are correctly returned.
            return a;
        }

        if constexpr (std::is_signed_v<T>) {
            if ((a < 0) != (b < 0)) {
                // Values are opposite sign; avoid overflow when
                // magnitudes are large.
                return (a + b) / 2;
            }
        }

        if (a < b) {
            return a + distance(a, b) / 2;
        } else {
            return b + distance(b, a) / 2;
        }
    }

    // Iterators
    // If not random-access, then a MUST be before b
    template<std::input_or_output_iterator Iter, std::sentinel_for<Iter> S>
    constexpr Iter midpoint(Iter a, const S& b)
    {
        std::ranges::advance(a, std::ranges::distance(a, b) / 2);
        return a;
    }

    // Aggregate types follow
    // Pattern can be extended, e.g. for popular geometry types

    template<affine_point T>
    constexpr std::complex<T> midpoint(const std::complex<T>& a, const std::complex<T>& b)
    {
        return {
            midpoint(a.real(), b.real()),
            midpoint(a.imag(), b.imag())
        };
    }

    template<affine_point T, std::size_t N>
    constexpr std::array<T,N> midpoint(const std::array<T,N>& a, const std::array<T,N>& b)
    {
        std::array<T,N> result;
        auto f = [](auto&& x, auto&& y) { return midpoint(x,y); };
        std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), result.begin(), f);
        return result;
    }
}

using detail::midpoint;
}
```

### // Tests

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

using toby::midpoint;

#include <climits>
TEST(midpoint, int)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(midpoint(0, 0), 0);
    EXPECT_EQ(midpoint(0, 1), 0);
    EXPECT_EQ(midpoint(0, 2), 1);
    EXPECT_EQ(midpoint(1, 3), 2);
    EXPECT_EQ(midpoint(4, 1), 2);
    EXPECT_EQ(midpoint(INT_MIN, 0), INT_MIN/2);
    EXPECT_EQ(midpoint(INT_MAX, 0), INT_MAX/2);
    EXPECT_EQ(midpoint(INT_MAX, -INT_MAX), 0);
}

#include <limits>
TEST(midpoint, double)
{
    static constexpr auto inf = std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();
    static constexpr auto nan = std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();
    EXPECT_EQ(midpoint(0.0, 0.0), 0.0);
    EXPECT_EQ(midpoint(1.0, 2.0), 1.5);
    EXPECT_EQ(midpoint(1.0, inf), inf);
    EXPECT_EQ(midpoint(1.0, -inf), -inf);
    EXPECT_EQ(midpoint(inf, inf), inf);
    EXPECT_EQ(midpoint(-inf, -inf), -inf);
    EXPECT_TRUE(std::isnan(midpoint(inf, -inf)));
    EXPECT_TRUE(std::isnan(midpoint(nan, 0.0)));
    EXPECT_TRUE(std::isnan(midpoint(0.0, nan)));
    EXPECT_TRUE(std::isnan(midpoint(nan, nan)));
}

#include <complex>
TEST(midpoint, complex)
{
    auto const a = std::complex{2,10};
    auto const b = std::complex{0,20};
    auto const c = std::complex{1,15};
    EXPECT_EQ(midpoint(a, b), c);
}

TEST(midpoint, pointer)
{
    char const s[50] = {};
    EXPECT_EQ(midpoint(s+1, s+25), s+13);
    EXPECT_EQ(midpoint(s+25, s+1), s+13);
}

#include <string_view>
TEST(midpoint, iterator)
{
    auto const s = std::string_view{"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"};
    EXPECT_EQ(*midpoint(s.begin(), s.end()), 'n');
    EXPECT_EQ(*midpoint(s.end(), s.begin()), 'n');
}

#include <list>
TEST(midpoint, bidi_iterator)
{
    auto const s = std::string_view{"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"};
    auto const l = std::list(s.begin(), s.end());
    EXPECT_EQ(*midpoint(l.begin(), l.end()), 'n');
}

#include <forward_list>
TEST(midpoint, forward_iterator)
{
    auto const s = std::string_view{"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"};
    auto const l = std::forward_list(s.begin(), s.end());
    EXPECT_EQ(*midpoint(l.begin(), l.end()), 'n');
}

#include <array>
TEST(midpoint, std_array)
{
    auto const a = std::array{ 0, 10, 20};
    auto const b = std::array{10, 10, 10};
    auto const c = std::array{ 5, 10, 15};
    EXPECT_EQ(midpoint(a, b), c);
}
```

Comment: I don’t have anything to add, but here’s a good video from CppCon on implementing [std::midpoint](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=sBtAGxBh-XI)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've done a good job of coming up to speed with language features and library organization.

Your `distance` for pointers is interesting, but takes a while to understand.

Note that if someone calls `midpoint(true,true)` it will be a compile-time error, but calling `midpoint<bool>(x1,x2)` will still call the template specialization, and ignore the plain function overload.

Your iterator code won't like single-pass iterators; does input_or_output_iterator exclude those or is that an orthogonal classification?

As for Ayxan's complaint about not knowing what "affine" meant, you could include a very brief comment in the concept body, pointing out that your concern is that subtraction can produce a result of a different type.  If you minimally word it along the lines of "this is what I need and this is what it's properly called" you will make it readable without bothering people who *do* know that term already or bloating up the code with documentation that's not really about the code.

Comment: I was thinking of creating some "discovery" tests, to prove we can't call the bool overload.  I'll look into that, and add some for the single-pass iterators too.

Comment: see https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1247697/Unit-Tests-for-Code-that-is-Supposed-to-Not-Compil

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I had been reading.  I just need to find time to actually put it into practice...

Comment: Yea, I remember discussing it a few days ago, but I thought it was on someone else's post.

Comment: Probably was - I either found it by Web search or followed a link from a comment I read on SE.

Comment: Nice that you found it, then :)  It would be appreciated it you upvoted it/bookmarked it on Codeproject; few people seem to ever incorporate that into the automated unit tests.

Answer (score 3):

1. `std::transform` is defined in `<algorithm>`. You should include that.
2. Have it work for ranges with minimal work:

```
template <std::ranges::range range>
constexpr auto midpoint(range &&r)
{
    return midpoint(std::ranges::begin(r), std::ranges::end(r));
}
```

3. I had look up what "affine" means. Perhaps not a big deal, but hinders the readability a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

Final version, incorporating suggestions from the other answers.

Changes made:

- Use detection idiom to ensure constraints are applied (includes a simple implementation of `is_detected_v`, since my platform doesn't have the standard one yet).
- Use `std::midpoint()` to handle pointer types.
- Constrain `bool` out rather than overloading, so explicit specialization is affected.
- Use `std::forward_iterator` concept, to prohibit single-pass iterators.
- Accept a range as alternative to iterators.

### Code

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <cmath>
#include <complex>
#include <concepts>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iterator>
#include <numeric>
#include <ranges>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

namespace toby
{
namespace detail
{
    // A point on an affine line can be compared with another, and has
    // a difference type (which may be the same type).
    template<typename T>
    concept affine_point
    =   std::regular<T>
        && !std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<T>, bool>
        && requires(T a, T b) { a < b; a + (b - a); };

    template<typename T>
    constexpr auto midpoint(const T* a, const T* b) {
        return std::midpoint(a, b);
    }
    template<affine_point T>
    constexpr T midpoint(const T& a, const T& b)
    {
        if (a == b) {
            // This ensures infinities are correctly returned.
            return a;
        }

        if constexpr (std::is_signed_v<T>) {
            if ((a < 0) != (b < 0)) {
                // Values are opposite sign; avoid overflow when
                // magnitudes are large.
                return (a + b) / 2;
            }
        }

        if (a < b) {
            return a + (b - a) / 2;
        } else {
            return b + (a - b) / 2;
        }
    }


    // Iterators and ranges
    // If not random-access, then a MUST precede b
    template<std::forward_iterator Iter, std::sentinel_for<Iter> S>
    constexpr Iter midpoint(Iter a, const S& b)
    {
        std::ranges::advance(a, std::ranges::distance(a, b) / 2);
        return a;
    }
    template <std::ranges::range Range>
    constexpr auto midpoint(const Range& r)
    {
        return midpoint(std::ranges::begin(r), std::ranges::end(r));
    }

    // Aggregate types follow
    // Pattern can be extended, e.g. for popular geometry types

    template<affine_point T>
    constexpr std::complex<T> midpoint(const std::complex<T>& a, const std::complex<T>& b)
    {
        return {
            midpoint(a.real(), b.real()),
            midpoint(a.imag(), b.imag())
        };
    }

    template<affine_point T, std::size_t N>
    constexpr std::array<T,N> midpoint(const std::array<T,N>& a, const std::array<T,N>& b)
    {
        std::array<T,N> result;
        auto f = [](auto&& x, auto&& y) { return midpoint(x,y); };
        std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), result.begin(), f);
        return result;
    }
}

using detail::midpoint;
}
```

### // Tests

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

using toby::midpoint;

#include <climits>
TEST(midpoint, int)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(midpoint(0, 0), 0);
    EXPECT_EQ(midpoint(0, 1), 0);
    EXPECT_EQ(midpoint(0, 2), 1);
    EXPECT_EQ(midpoint(1, 3), 2);
    EXPECT_EQ(midpoint(4, 1), 2);
    EXPECT_EQ(midpoint(INT_MIN, 0), INT_MIN/2);
    EXPECT_EQ(midpoint(INT_MAX, 0), INT_MAX/2);
    EXPECT_EQ(midpoint(INT_MAX, -INT_MAX), 0);
}

#include <limits>
TEST(midpoint, double)
{
    static constexpr auto inf = std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();
    static constexpr auto nan = std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();
    EXPECT_EQ(midpoint(0.0, 0.0), 0.0);
    EXPECT_EQ(midpoint(1.0, 2.0), 1.5);
    EXPECT_EQ(midpoint(1.0, inf), inf);
    EXPECT_EQ(midpoint(1.0, -inf), -inf);
    EXPECT_EQ(midpoint(inf, inf), inf);
    EXPECT_EQ(midpoint(-inf, -inf), -inf);
    EXPECT_TRUE(std::isnan(midpoint(inf, -inf)));
    EXPECT_TRUE(std::isnan(midpoint(nan, 0.0)));
    EXPECT_TRUE(std::isnan(midpoint(0.0, nan)));
    EXPECT_TRUE(std::isnan(midpoint(nan, nan)));
}

#include <complex>
TEST(midpoint, complex)
{
    auto const a = std::complex{2,10};
    auto const b = std::complex{0,20};
    auto const c = std::complex{1,15};
    EXPECT_EQ(midpoint(a, b), c);
}

TEST(midpoint, pointer)
{
    char const s[50] = {};
    EXPECT_EQ(midpoint(s+1, s+25), s+13);
    EXPECT_EQ(midpoint(s+25, s+1), s+13);
}

#include <string_view>
TEST(midpoint, iterator)
{
    auto const s = std::string_view{"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"};
    EXPECT_EQ(*midpoint(s.begin(), s.end()), 'n');
    EXPECT_EQ(*midpoint(s.end(), s.begin()), 'n');
    EXPECT_EQ(*midpoint(s), 'n');
}

#include <list>
TEST(midpoint, bidi_iterator)
{
    auto const s = std::string_view{"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"};
    auto const l = std::list(s.begin(), s.end());
    EXPECT_EQ(*midpoint(l.begin(), l.end()), 'n');
    EXPECT_EQ(*midpoint(l), 'n');
}

#include <forward_list>
TEST(midpoint, forward_iterator)
{
    auto const s = std::string_view{"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"};
    auto const l = std::forward_list(s.begin(), s.end());
    EXPECT_EQ(*midpoint(l.begin(), l.end()), 'n');
    EXPECT_EQ(*midpoint(l), 'n');
}

#include <array>
TEST(midpoint, std_array)
{
    auto const a = std::array{ 0, 10, 20};
    auto const b = std::array{10, 10, 10};
    auto const c = std::array{ 5, 10, 15};
    EXPECT_EQ(midpoint(a, b), c);
}

#if 1
// use detection idiom to ensure invalid overloads don't exist
// Inspired from library fundamentals TS v3
namespace {
    template <class AlwaysVoid, template<class...> class Op, class... Args>
    struct detector : std::false_type {};

    template <template<class...> class Op, class... Args>
    struct detector<std::void_t<Op<Args...>>, Op, Args...> : std::true_type {};

    template <template<class...> class Op, class... Args>
    constexpr bool is_detected_v = detector<void, Op, Args...>::value;
}
#else

#include <experimental/type_traits>
    using std::is_detected_v;

#endif

template<typename T, typename U = T>
using midpoint_exists = decltype(midpoint(std::declval<T>(), std::declval<U>()));


//static constexpr bool a = is_detected<midpoint_exists, int, int>;
static_assert(is_detected_v<midpoint_exists, int>);
static_assert(!is_detected_v<midpoint_exists, bool>);
static_assert(!is_detected_v<midpoint_exists, bool&>);

static_assert(!is_detected_v<midpoint_exists, std::istream_iterator<char>>);
```

Comment: Strictly speaking affine space does not require points to be ordered. For example, complex numbers form an affine space. So maybe `affine_ordered_point` is a better name?

Comment: If you want to use `std::midpoint` for pointers, be aware that it rounds towards the first argument, not necessarily the smaller one.